# Loading CSS from cloud

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to load a CSS file into my page.  This CSS file does not reside in my resource folder.  I only have the full link to it - it resides on a CDN (ie: cloud files).

This CSS needs to be loaded after all other stylesheets loaded in the page.  I am currently loading my "normal" stylesheets in `<f:facet name="last">`.  But now I want to load the other sheet.  Basically what I would need is something of the sort :

```
<f:facet name="last">
    <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap.min.css" library="styles" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="styles.css" library="styles" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="http://my.link.to/stylesheet/sheet.css" />
</f:facet>
```

But `outputStylesheet` doesn't work with a link, and using the plain old `link` tag doesn't work in the `last facet`.

I am using `Primefaces` so I want the `bootstrap`, `styles.css`, and my linked CSS to be loaded AFTER the `Primefaces` styles -> the reason why they are in `f:facet name="last"`

Using:

- Mojarra 2.1.23
- Primefaces 3.5
- Omnifaces 1.6

Running on :

- Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: Can you post your template xhtml that includes the above facet

Answer (score 0):

Through standard JSF 2 tags, this is not currently possible. You will have to create a custom ResourceHandler which will fetch the files from the cloud.

If you're open to using external libraries, the excellent library [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org) already has a resource handler for your case - [CDNResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler)

See also:

- [Stackoverflow Omnifaces info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/omnifaces/info)

Comment: This works if you have the file in your library (ie: the `web.xml` needs to have this resource and it's URL).  In my case, the resource (stylesheet) is coming from the database.  Say I have events, and a custom CSS (that may of may not be there) in the event table - I cannot put all these resources in my `web.xml`.

Comment: In that case you can always create your own ResourceHandler implementation. You can refer to [this example](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/09/12/jsf-graphicimage-from-database/) for starters